# Encountering Error with Pig Code

Tags: java

My variable names are pretty stupid near the bottom but that's not the point. Line 110 says that I'm making an else statement without the if and I'm nearly certain the if is there. Please help in any way you can.

Thank you

```
import java.util.*;

public class hw7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            int turnScores = 0;
            int totalScores = 0;
            int turnScores2 = 0;
            int totalScores2 = 0;
            int dice;
            int dice2;
            String input = "r";
            char repeat;
            boolean peppers;
            peppers = true;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            Random randomNumbers = new Random();

            System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

            while(totalScores < 20 || totalScores2 < 20)
            {
              do
              {
                  dice = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;

                  System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);

                  if(dice == 1)
                  {
                      turnScores = 0;
                      System.out.print("Your lose your turn!");
                      System.out.println("Your Total is " + totalScores);
                      break;
                  }
                  else
                  {         
                     turnScores += dice;
                     System.out.print("Your turn score is " + turnScores);
                     System.out.println(" and your total scores is " + totalScores);
                     System.out.println("If you hold, you will have " + turnScores 
                                       + " points.");
                     System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.");
                     input = keyboard.nextLine();
                     repeat = input.charAt(0);

                     if(repeat == 'h')
                     {
                        break;
                     }
                  }
              }
              while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1);               

                 totalScores += turnScores;
                 peppers = peppers(turnScores, turnScores2);
                 System.out.println("Your scores is " + totalScores);
                 turnScores = 0;

              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("It is the computer's turn.");

              do
              {
                  dice2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1; 
                  System.out.println("The computer rolled: " + dice2);

                  if(dice2 == 1)
                  {
                      turnScores2 = 0;
                      System.out.print("The computer lost its turn!");
                      System.out.println(" Computer total is " + totalScores2);
                      break;             
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      turnScores2 += dice2;
                      if(turnScores2 >= 20 || (totalScores2 + turnScores2) >= 20 )
                      {
                          System.out.println("The computer holds");
                          break;      
                      }
                  }
               }

              while(dice2 != 1 || turnScores2 < 20);
              totalScores2 += turnScores2;
              System.out.println("The computer's scores is " + totalScores2 + "\n");
              turnScores2 = 0;
            }
    }



public static boolean peppers(int chili, int ghost)
    {
        boolean done;
        done = true;


        if(chili >= 20);
        {
            done = false;
            System.out.println(" YOU WIN!!!");
            return done;
        }
        else (ghost >= 20);
        {
            done = false;
            System.out.println(" COMPUTER WINS");
            return done;
        }
        /*else 
        {
            return done;
        }
            */
    }


}
```

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer with a minimal example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semicolons in `if(chili >= 20);` and `else (ghost >= 20);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean peppers(int chili, int ghost)
{
    boolean done;
    done = true;
    if(chili >= 20)
    {
        done = false;
        System.out.println(" YOU WIN!!!");
    }
    else if (ghost >= 20)
    {
        System.out.println(" COMPUTER WINS");

    }
    return done;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
else (ghost >= 20);
```

with

```
else if (ghost >= 20)
```

and remove the semicolons after the if-statement.